# Run bash function every x minute(s)

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a bash script with a function named `speedtest` created like this:

```
function speedtest
    {
            echo $time_min; 
            echo $(date +%R),"$(speedtest-cli --csv)" >>temp.csv # Outputs van datum en speedtest in temp.csv
            cut -d, -f1,8 < temp.csv >> output2.csv; # Verwijderd onnodige info uit temp en plaatst het in output.csv
            awk -F , -v OFS=, '$3/=1000000' <output2 >output2.csv # Zet bits/s om naar Mbp/s
            rm temp.csv;
    }
```

I would like to run this function exactly x minutes.
Note that the function takes some time to run.
If I run it every x minutes,
that's not the same thing as running it, sleeping for x minutes and then running it again.
I want to start the function exactly every x minutes.

Comment: Why not schedule as a cron job?

Comment: I Can't ( I'm not allowed to) i just need to create a script that runs this function for x amount of minutes.

Comment: `bash`'s built-in `sleep` allows taking single character parameters , so wrap it into `while sleep  3m; do  function_name; done`. And if you need autostart when you log in, make it a script and launch it via Startup Applications app, or manually via . desktop file.

Comment: Or make it a script and use `watch` command. Also, why are you passing data back and forth ? Just let awk handle everything via pipe, no need for cut and writing to files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're not allowed to use cron.
In that case, you could use an infinite loop calls this function *in the background* and then sleeps for `x` minutes:

```
while true; do speedtest & sleep 60; done
```

Just make sure to sleep long enough so that the current `speedtest` call terminates before the sleep is over, to avoid multiple instances of the process running in parallel.

If you don't want to keep a terminal open with this running,
you can do this in a `screen` or `tmux` session.

Comment: I have used this before the problem with this is that it counts the delay time + the time that it accutally takes for running it. I need it to run exactly every x minutes.

Comment: @Cyber_Star I see. I updated my post accordingly.